# Angularjs - launch a function from a remote service before implementing routes and controller

Tags: angularjs, service, routes

I develop an application with Angularjs. I'm a novice and I would like to retrieve data about a user thanks to a specific function defined in a remote service (developed by me) before to implement the routes and the views / controllers (for secure access reason to the views).

In fact a user is identified thanks to an external system (not developed by myself) and redirected to my application. I have developed in parallel a remote service for using in various application. Thus when the user is entered to the main application, the login is retrieved and I would like to call the function from my external service that I developed in order to retrieve the information about the user (role, personal data, ...).

The function from the remote service works perfectly when it is called in the various controllers in my application. But I would like to call once the function before to implement the routes (for security reasons: not access to the specific views if the role is not correct).

Could you please tell me how to do that?

I have tried this solution (http://www.frangular.com/2012/12/initialisations-avant-routage-avec-resolve.html) but it doesn't work:

```
var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'RemoteService']);

// THE REMOTE SERVICE
app.factory('RemoteServiceFunction', ['RemoteServiceFactory', function (RemoteServiceFactory) {
    RemoteServiceFactory.Auth_getUserFromLogin(userid)
    .success(function(personInfo){
        return personInfo;
    });
}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){

    // FUNCTION USING THE REMOTE SERVICE IN ORDER TO INJECT DATA IN THE ROUTES
    function wait(RemoteServiceFunction) {
        return RemoteServiceFunction;
    }
    wait.$inject = ['RemoteServiceFunction'];


    $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
      controller: 'ctrlContacts', 
        resolve: {
            personInfo: wait
        }           
    })
    .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
      controller: 'ctrlViewContacts',
        resolve: {
            personInfo: wait
        }         
    })
    .when('/search-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/fastSearch.html',
      controller: 'ctrlContactSearch',
        resolve: {
            personInfo: wait
        }         
    })  
    .when('/add-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/manageContact.html',
      controller: 'ctrlAddContacts',
        resolve: {
            personInfo: wait
        }         
    }) 
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
});    

//THE CONTROLERS WITH DEPENDANCIES INJECTED
app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, ContactService, personInfo){
    // ....
}
```

Although the request of the remote service is correctly called (visible in Firebug), the data contain in personInfo are considered as "undefined" in the controller.

Could you please help me to find a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return a value from *RemoteServiceFunction*. in your case the promise itself. the return statement in your success handler does not serve as the return function of the *RemoteServiceFunction* provider (but be aware that userid is still missing and not bounded or in global scope).

```
app.factory('RemoteServiceFunction', ['RemoteServiceFactory', function (RemoteServiceFactory) {
    return RemoteServiceFactory.Auth_getUserFromLogin(userid);
}]);
```

additionally I would change

```
function wait(RemoteServiceFunction) {
    return RemoteServiceFunction;
}
wait.$inject = ['RemoteServiceFunction'];
```

to

```
var wait = ['RemoteServiceFunction', function(RemoteServiceFunction) {
    return RemoteServiceFunction;
}];
```

(or inject *RemoteServiceFunction* directly into your controller, since the route change will fail if the *RemoteServiceFunction* failed)

Comment: Many thanks for the response,

it works perfectly.  By this way how can I authorize the access to the view according to the value returned by the promised "peonrsInfo.data["role"]? add a function in the resolve?

As I need to test the user role returned by the promise in order to authorize the display of the view, I would like to know if the way used is the best way to do that, or if it exist a better method to implement the role verification for a user (with a remote service) in an angularjs application?

Comment: there are multiple ways of implementing role based access in angluar, e.g., listening to route change events. As long as the route or Controller is prevented from being invoked it's fine, but don't forget to check a user's privileges on the serverside too. A more advanced technique would be to have a Hateoas based REST Api that omits links based on the granted authorities, which results in a data or hypermedia driven user interface. I'll post a plunkr snippet here if you accept my answer!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you show me an example in order to do that? (listening to route change events)? I have accepted your answer. thanks –